# Await in Nuxt 3 Script Setup

Tags: async-await, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

Whenever I use **await** in top level Script Setup, it doesn't work properly except I use it in the **onMounted** hook and inside the **nextTick** function.
I want to know why and what is the recommended way to fetch data before loading page

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Also, do you have some code to share as of what is not working? Give a read to that one: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching#useasyncdata